# Shoes and shirts after football matches?

Tags: football, equipment

What is the destination of the football players' shoes and shirt after each official match?
After the matches it is easy to view players exchanges eachother the shirts. Does they use a new shirts every match?

What about the shoes? I find comfortable to play with used shoes because they fit well to the feet, but I do not know about the football players

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.lbc.co.uk/what-happens-football-kit-after-the-game-21318) article:

> The kit man takes three shirts per player to each game – one per half,
>   plus a spare for emergencies. Afterwards, he collects and launders
>   them, ready for next week. For big games, the club permits the players
>   to swap or keep their shirts, but that is agreed beforehand and the
>   players are fined if they do it when they’re not allowed.

But I imagine this depends on the player, club, country and meaning of the game.

Regarding boots, Chris Smalling of Manchester United offers some insight [here](http://www.manutd.com/en/News-And-Features/United-Uncovered/News/2014/Feb/Issue-55/Chris-Smalling-football-boots-feature.aspx):

> In general most players wear a pair for training and then a different
>   pair for matches. You'll start off wearing them in training to break
>   them in and then when you feel they're ready you'll put them on for
>   matchdays.